Spring Integration Http.outboundGateway.expectResponseType - display unexpected message
With the following code;
.handle(
  Http
    .outboundGateway("http://localhost/something")
    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    .expectedResponseType(Something.class)
)
.<Something>handle((p, h) -> { .... })

I would expect the JSON representation of Something.class to be received. However, we have a data-checking firewall, which could reject the incoming JSON and send a completely different response (e.g. XML).
When the incoming message is not the expected JSON, the error_channel stack trace reports the URI and why it failed to parse.
My current solution is to always expect a response type of String. Then within the following handle use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(payload, Something.class). If the read throws an exception, then I log the original payload and return null.
Is there a way of expecting the correct class (Something.class not String.class), but still report the original response when parsing fails?
Edit #1 After Artum's initial answer;
With reference to the example for EerhaApplication at Spring Integration Reference Documentation
With the following modifications;
.handle(
  Http
    .outboundGateway("http://localhost/something")
    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    .expectedResponseType(Something.class)
  , a -> a.advice(myAdvice())
)
.<Something>handle((p, h) -> { .... })

@Bean
public Advice myAdvice() {
  ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice eerha = new 
  ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
  eerha.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was BAAAAAAD ' + #exception.cause.message");
  eerha.setFailureChannelName("baaad");
  eerha.setTrapException(true);
  return eerha;
}

Both the returned evaluationResult and failedMessage refer to the Message that was the input to the OutboundGateway. I wanted to see the raw output from the OutboundGateway, before it fails on marshalling  via expectedResponseType.

If you don't want to parse a response yourself as you mentioned, but still rely on the JSON back to your Something and fail otherwise, then consider to use an ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice. This one is, essentially, try..catch on the specific endpoint: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/6.4/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice

The advice returns the incoming payload to the gateway, not the raw response from the gateway. See edit above.

I believe the failure is there is the exception thrown from a gateway. However you say that you'd like to see the raw response before the RestTemplate tries to unmarshal it. That is indeed not what we can do with try..catch. See a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor abstraction to be injected into the RestTemplate.

I am only interested in logging unparseable messages. I suspect that if I were to use ClientHttpRequestInterceptor I would have to log every message as it is before the parse phase. Raising or lowering log levels "after the fact" is impracticle. So I guess for now, having expectedResponseType(String.class) then having try..catch on the following handle() which performs the parse, is the most concise solution?

As I said before: that ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice to be applied for this outbound gateway is exactly the same try..catch. And you can see a reason of the exception in its stack trace. But yes, if you'd like to preserve an original response, then you indeed don't have a choice but process it afterwards. So, you will be able to parse it to desired model or have the whole response for error handling. However it looks like AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter throws an HttpMessageNotReadableException with an inputMessage. So, that response is still available in the error.
